# After updating magento to 1.9.3.1 my site has error in export products

Tags: magento-1.9, overrides, export

While exporting products i am getting blank section in entity attributes section as per in screenshot[image]
and getting below error in error log file:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class Mage_ImportExport_Model_Export_Entity_Product contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods 
(Mage_ImportExport_Model_Export_Entity_Abstract::exportFile) in
/.../app/code/local/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Export/Entity/Product.php on line 35
class Mage_ImportExport_Model_Export_Entity_Product extends Mage_ImportExport_Model_Export_Entity_Abstract{
```

Comment: Could you post the content of this file please ?

Comment: how can i sent you whole file in this ? from app/code/local/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Export/Entity/Product.php file? could you please guide me?

Comment: Edit your question, copy the content of the file and paste it into your question

Comment: i have edited my question please check @RaphaelatDigitalPianism

Comment: Are those two lines the only thing you have in this file ??

Comment: Obviously not!!!It is very large file @RaphaelatDigitalPianism

Comment: Please add the full file then

Comment: It is not allowing to place full code of my file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48933/discussion-between-gaurav-jariwala-and-raphael-at-digital-pianism).

Comment: Hi @RaphaelatDigitalPianism i sent full code in chat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an old version of the file under `app/code/local` which is not compatible with 1.9.3.1

I'm not sure why you have this copied version here but I suggest you:

- either back it up and replace it with a copy of `app/code/code/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Export/Entity/Product‌​.php` then apply your custom changes to this new version
- delete it if you don't need it anymore

Comment: Ok,again perfect man!!!Thank you saved my time, i do not take a look about this one scenario.